# MySQL caching (innodb_buffer_pool_size vs query_cache_*)

Tags: mysql, cache

What's the relation between:

**innodb_buffer_pool_size** and **query_cache_***

Both are use for caching queries but what's the difference? Can I use both?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffer pool is for caching retrieved table and index data in memory, query cache just caches the parsed mysql queries and their results. The former is much larger and usually far more important. Sure you can use both.

Comment: The query cache does not cache queries, it caches result sets from queries. (but the rest is correct). (cf Oracle where queries and their execution plans are cached).

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Sorry I missed the result set, but in mysql the queries are cached along with the result set.

Answer (score 0):

**innodb_buffer_pool_size** = caches the tables for better response times

**query_cache** = for remembering queries to get them faster the next time you execute the *same* query

Comment: No, the innodb_buffer_pool caches rows of data read, not tables.